Cassiopeia mobile menu collapse bug
I have discovered a bug in the Cassiopeia theme, and I can't find a solution to it, and I don't even know what's causing it.
Searching, I found such a page, and it appears here, on several browsers: https://cassiopeia.joomla.com/help/menu-module
When in mobile view, and I open the hamburger menu ("Page Modules" - menu module settings in the "Advanced" tab under "Layout" - "Collapsible Dropdown" ), then open the submenus, any of them, then close the entire hamburger menu as is, then open it again... If you play this for a while, randomly, something will get stuck, and suddenly their collapsible submenus won't open. I'm watching the inspector, can't find the cause of the error.
Has anyone experienced anything similar?
Does anyone know what could cause this bug?
I've tried it on several sites, J4, J5, fresh, new installation, where nothing is configured but the menu module "Collapsible Dropdown" and the error persists anyway.
